# Can i insert data to influxdb from a .log file

Tags: influxdb

I have a file with data in a .log file. how can i get inserted into the database like the NOAA_water_database they suggest in the documentation.
the link to the doc is below
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLI command influx has an option  called `-import` to import data to influx. Refer more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/shell/#import-data-from-a-file-with-import).
In the same document you mentioned in question there is a command to import data to influx

```
influx -import -path=NOAA_data.txt -precision=s -database=NOAA_water_database
```

Comment: Sorted. I attempted with a data set i generated and it works fine. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Inserting the data from a log file to influx DB is possible if the lines of a log file are in line protocol.
Please refer below URL :

https://community.influxdata.com/t/writing-logs-manually-into-influxdb/6247/4